# where to put this math repo reference link?

Tags: support

I asked this in chat a few days ago, but had no takers: I came across this amazing **math formula repository** done by the US National Institute of Standards and Technology (**NIST**). I think it could be useful for math + blender phreaks ( like me :))

- where should I post it - on meta or on main, e.g ask my own question then answer it?

[dlmf.nist.gov](http://dlmf.nist.gov)

I know exterior links are frowned on because the go stale and die, but this one is an entire subdomain that's been around a bit, so it'll like stay good.  (It didn't seem to fit well under the rubric of Python, although, obviously, you'd code the formulas *in* python.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason to ask a new question (I can't think of how you could ask it and keep it on topic). Posting on meta is not the proper place either.
Because it is just a link (unrelated to blender) there is no place where it can stand alone.

The best place on BSE is our [Resource for blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/15355/2217) list. You may want to add a new answer, because all the existing categories there don't really fit for a math link.

Comment: Thx - David ... isn't this resource thing a systemic issue for all SE sites? I mean, it's not easy to *find* such. Here, for instance, I searched for as many of them as I could find, and added to one, but had no way to know that the page in your answer is blender.se's defacto main resource page.  Does the SE template have a spot for this, e.g. in the bottom menu, or perhaps at the top left corner (like the short links in chat)?